# How to avoid motion sickness in a theme park?

Tags: summer, health

I love theme parks. I am a huge fan of roller coasters and other kind of strong attractions. The problem is that I usually feel sick fairly soon, sometimes even after the first or second ride.

That means that I usually have to stop riding for a while, not trying all the roller coasters in the park or just giving up strong sensations for the day.

Of course, that also slows down my friends, who often stay with me and don't ride (or ride less) the strongest roller coasters because of that. Besides, I cannot help but feeling that I am wasting money when I can't fully enjoy my ticket.

So my question is:

> Are there any way to avoid or reduce this kind of sickness in theme parks?

Edit: my original question was worded with "dizziness" instead of "motion sickness" because a translation mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question is regarding dizziness; but, your details suggest motion sickness which is related.

Here's an article on the overall symptom
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dizziness

Dizziness involves some trouble with your balance. You would have trouble walking; and, in severe cases just trying to sit upright on the ground would be difficult.

You can reduce dizzy spells.

- Avoid rapid changes in position that affects your blood pressure.
- Avoid rapid changes in your head position
- Eliminate or decrease use of products that impair circulation: nicotine, caffeine, and salt
- Avoid things that increase your stress levels

(Avoid hazardous activities if you are feeling the least bit dizzy.)

You can lessen the effects of motion sickness

- Ride where you can look toward your destination without tilting your head.
- Don't read or look down
- Don't watch or talk to another traveler who is having motion sickness
- Avoid strong odours and spicy or greasy foods
- Try any one of the many motion sickness remedies

Here is more relevant information about both of their causes and treatments
http://www.ccent.com/vertigo-dizziness-cause-california-visalia.htm#dizzy

Here is more specific information about Motion Sickness, its causes and some techniques to reduce its effects
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sickness

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, in my language we use the same word for both things, but yes, I was referring to motion sickness. Thank you for your answer, I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try what ballet dancers do: keep your eyes focused and your head aimed at a single spot *outside* the ride, and *snap* your head to a new position, if need be, rather than *slooowly* moving it.

Also, don't eat before you go for a ride... urk

Comment: The technique is called "spotting." It is a technique used to reduce dizziness but can make motion sickness symptoms worse.

Answer (score 1):

Motion sickness is caused in simple terms by your eyes and ears (the part which sends balance info not auditory info) sending dramatically different sensory input to the brain. For example, if the balance part of your ears tell your brain that your are stationary but your eyes see the world going past you like a bat out of hell then motion sickness occurs.

A good example of this happens when driving in a car. The driver is looking down the road and the 2 senses are in balance - no motion sickness.
The child in the rear seat is looking out of the window and seeing the world zoom by. The child's senses are out of balance- motion sickness occurs.

In the question posed with roller coasters simply focus ahead to a single point to where the roller coaster is heading and avoid looking at your surroundings whizzing by. Enjoy the ride.

Answer (score 0):

Suck on Ginger Candy.
Buy from store or make your [own](http://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-Ginger-Candy/).